# Driving cost - methods

Tags: java

**This is a problem for school**

Write a method `drivingCost()` with input parameters `drivenMiles`, `milesPerGallon`, and `dollarsPerGallon`, that returns the dollar cost to drive those miles. All items are of type `double`. If the method is called with

```
50 20.0 3.1599
```

the method returns `7.89975`.

Define that method in a program whose inputs are the car's miles/gallon and the gas dollars/gallon (both doubles). Output the gas cost for 10 miles, 50 miles, and 400 miles, by calling your `drivingCost()` method three times.

Output each floating-point value with two digits after the decimal point, which can be achieved as follows:

```
System.out.printf("%.2f", yourValue);
```

The output ends with a newline.

Ex: If the input is:

```
20.0 3.1599
```

the output is:

```
1.58 7.90 63.20
```

Your program must define and call a method:
`public static double drivingCost(double drivenMiles, double milesPerGallon, double dollarsPerGallon)`

**So far my code seems to make sense, but I keep getting this error, and I am not sure what it means,**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:937)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
```

**Here is my code**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LabProgram {
   
   public static double drivingCost(double drivenMiles, double milesPerGallon, double dollarsPerGallon) {
      double totalCost = (dollarsPerGallon * drivenMiles) / milesPerGallon;
      return totalCost;
   }
   
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      double milesPerGallon = scnr.nextDouble();
      double dollarsPerGallon = scnr.nextDouble();
      double drivenMiles = scnr.nextDouble();
      
      System.out.printf("%.2f ", drivingCost(drivenMiles, milesPerGallon, dollarsPerGallon) * 10);
      System.out.printf("%.2f ", drivingCost(drivenMiles, milesPerGallon, dollarsPerGallon) * 50);
      System.out.printf("%.2f\n", drivingCost(drivenMiles, milesPerGallon, dollarsPerGallon) * 400);
   }
}
```

Comment: What environment are you running the code in? Some require that you specify the input to standard input before running the program.

Comment: Cannot Reproduce

Comment: Hi, my answer helped you?

Answer (score 3):

`drivenMiles` is not one of the inputs, you provide it in the calls to `drivingCost()`.

```
  System.out.printf("%.2f ", drivingCost(10, milesPerGallon, dollarsPerGallon));
  System.out.printf("%.2f ", drivingCost(50, milesPerGallon, dollarsPerGallon));
  System.out.printf("%.2f\n", drivingCost(400, milesPerGallon, dollarsPerGallon));
```

The reason you are getting `NoSuchElementException` is that there are only two input parameters and you are trying to read three parameters.

Answer (score 3):

To avoid this kind of errors, always check user input.

It can be done using `hasNextDouble`:

```java
Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
double milesPerGallon = (scnr.hasNextDouble() ? sc.nextDouble() : 0.0;
```

Also always watch out `Divison by Zero`.
The code will throw a exception if `milesPerGallon` is zero. So, solve this using ternary operand:

```java
double totalCost = (dollarsPerGallon * drivenMiles) / (milesPerGallon!=0?milesPerGallon:1);
```

Although the code above result into a **correct result**.
Changing to code below make a little more sense:

```java
return (drivenMiles / (milesPerGallon!=0?milesPerGallon:1)) * dollarsPerGallon;
```

The correct code is:

```java
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LabProgram {
   
   public static double drivingCost(double drivenMiles, double milesPerGallon, double dollarsPerGallon) {
      //Avoid Division by zero
      return (drivenMiles / (milesPerGallon!=0?milesPerGallon:1)) * dollarsPerGallon;
   }
   
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      //Fix user input to US number formats 
      Locale.setDefault(Locale.ENGLISH);
      
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      
      double milesPerGallon = (scnr.hasNextDouble()) ? scnr.nextDouble() : 0.00; 
      double dollarsPerGallon = (scnr.hasNextDouble()) ? scnr.nextDouble() : 0.00;
      
      System.out.printf("10mi: $%.2f "  , drivingCost( 10, milesPerGallon, dollarsPerGallon));
      System.out.printf("50mi: $%.2f "  , drivingCost( 50, milesPerGallon, dollarsPerGallon));
      System.out.printf("400mi: $%.2f\n", drivingCost(400, milesPerGallon, dollarsPerGallon));
   }
}
```

Compile this with: `javac LabProgram.java`
Run this with: `java LabProgram`

Output:

```
20.0 3.1599
10mi: $1.58 50mi: $7.90 400mi: $63.20`
```

Answer (score 1):

Although I'm too late here, still posting this for anyone struggling with this. The following code gave me the correct output:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LabProgram {
   public static void main(String[] args) {

      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

      Double milesPerGallon = 0.0;
      Double dollarsPerGallon = 0.0;
      Double gasCost = 0.0;
      Double gasCost20 = 0.0;
      Double gasCost75 = 0.0;
      Double gasCost500 = 0.0;

      milesPerGallon = scnr.nextDouble();
      dollarsPerGallon = scnr.nextDouble();
      gasCost = dollarsPerGallon / milesPerGallon;
      gasCost20 = gasCost * 20;

      System.out.printf("%.2f", gasCost20);
      System.out.print(" ");
         gasCost75 = gasCost * 75;
      System.out.printf("%.2f", gasCost75);
      System.out.print(" ");
         gasCost500 = gasCost * 500;
      System.out.printf("%.2f%n", gasCost500);
   }
}
```